# Jaccard Analysis Similarity

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I'm trying to do a Jaccard Analysis from R.

But, after the processing, my result columns are NULL.

I've tried to do a solution from many ways, but the problem still remains.

Can anyone help me please?

```
#######################PROCESSING JACCARD ANAYLSIS###################
Jaccard = function (x, y) {
M.11 = sum(x == 1 & y == 1)
M.10 = sum(x == 1 & y == 0)
M.01 = sum(x == 0 & y == 1)
return (M.11 / (M.11 + M.10 + M.01))
}

input.variables = data.frame(Q6_01, Q6_02, Q6_03, Q6_04, Q6_05, Q6_06, Q6_07, Q6_08)


m = matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(input.variables), ncol = length(input.variables))
for (r in 1:length(input.variables)) {
  for (c in 1:length(input.variables)) {
    if (c == r) {
      m[r,c] = 1
    } else if (c > r) {
      m[r,c] = Jaccard(input.variables[,r], input.variables[,c])
    }
  }
}

variable.names = sapply(input.variables, attr, "label")
colnames(m) = variable.names
rownames(m) = variable.names   

jaccards = m
```

[image]

Comment: What does  `variable.names` contain?

Comment: ...  as generally dataframes do not have labels they have `names`  --> perhaps why you are seeing NULL. Try with `names(input.variables)`

Comment: Hi there, what is the output of `sapply(input.variables, attr, "label")`? looks like there might not be any attribute called `"label"` in your `input.variables` and you are getting a list of `NULL`s from `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to calculate Jaccard similarity, I would suggest checking out the [vegan](/questions/tagged/vegan) package. The `vegdist()` function can be used to calculate lots of different similarity/dissimilarity measures. Check out `?vegdist`.

For Jaccard, you would use `vegdist(your_dataframe_name, method = "jaccard")`